# How to set my virtual box display for Red Hat Linux to 1366X768

Tags: virtualbox, display, virtualization

I have installed Red Hat Linux on my virtual box and i can't set the display of VM to 1366X768. The display option in red hat linux shows only 1024x768, 800X600, 400x600.

Comment: Did you install guest additions?

Comment: What is guest addition and how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the virtual machine open, click on Devices --> Install Guest Additions.  See image below.

[image]